# cloning an element in angular, and tying up the attached directives

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have built a function that correctly appends a new row to a table when the last row gets the focus.

This works successfully, but **the directive is no longer triggering the cloned row**
How do I fix the clone so that the elements are added with directives attached.

I need to trigger the directive **`link`** after the clone is complete.

each row has a directive attached.

```
<tr add-table-row-empty>
    <td>...
```

And this is the directive.

```
module Panda {

@directive('$log', '$compile')
export class AddTableRowEmpty implements ng.IDirective
{
    public restrict: string = "A";
    constructor(public $log: ng.ILogService, public $compile: ng.ICompileService)
    {
    }

    public link: Function = ($scope: any, element: angular.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: angular.IAttributes) => {
        var inputs = $('input', element);
        inputs.on('focus', () => this.addIfLastRow(element));
    }

    private addIfLastRow(element: angular.IAugmentedJQuery) {
        if (!($(element).is(':last-child')))
            return;
        this.addRow(element);
    }

    private addRow(element: angular.IAugmentedJQuery)
    {
        // this should do a deep clone including all events etc.
        var clone = element.clone(true, true);
        $("input", clone).each((i, _) => $(_).val(""));
        element.after(clone);
        clone
            .hide()
            .fadeIn(1000);
    }
}
panda.directive("addTableRowEmpty", <any>AddTableRowEmpty);
}
```

Comment: Why do you clone elements? Why don't you simply add a new object to your array in the model, and let ng-repeat do its job of generating the new row based on the new element of the array?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this solution is a bit of a hybrid at the moment, the existing elements are currently generated server side. I agree it's not ideal. I would still like to know how to clone and attach the elements.

Comment: @Jim you should have a look at the $compile service. You need to pass your html trough that to make the angular stuff work. There's probably a duplicate for this somewhere on SO. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: thanks, $compile seems to do the trick.

Comment: toskv, don't you want to post an answer. I will accept it, and you can get a few points.